# jQuery not running in Safari

Tags: jquery, safari

I've have built at pop-up message to make people sign up for a newsletter. 
The jQuery code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (localStorage.getItem('popState') != 'shown') {
    $('#signup-box').delay(3000).show(0);
    localStorage.setItem('popState', 'shown')
  };
  $('#signup-button').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'white')
  }, function() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#AF2729')
  });
  $('#signup-button').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('color', '#AF2729')
  }, function() {
$(this).css('color', 'white')
  });
})
```

The code works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari, neither on a Mac nor an iPhone. Does anyone know why? 
I have included the script just before the pop-up html like this:

```
<script>type="text/javascript" src="/globalassets/documents/signup.js"</script>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages in console?

Comment: No. The pop-up is showing up, but it does not work when I hover over the button.

Comment: 1)You should put the script before the body tag closing. 2) you've created 2 different function for the same action(hover) on the same element(#signup-button), it's a little bit strange.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work